# Updating the model with file URL to be saved on submit

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I have been able to successfully upload an image with a custom field template calling a function that handles the upload. It then gathers the return url and from there, i have no idea how to insert it back into the field for saving with the form.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Here is my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-admin', 'backand', 'ngFileUpload']);


//myApp.directive('dashboardSummary', require('./dashboards/dashboardSummary'));


myApp.config(['BackandProvider', function(BackandProvider) {
BackandProvider.setAppName('');
BackandProvider.setSignUpToken('');
BackandProvider.setAnonymousToken('');

}]);


myApp.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

// add a response interceptor
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
  var extractedData;
  // .. to look for getList operations
  if (operation === "getList") {
    // .. and handle the data and meta data
    extractedData = data.data;
    extractedData.meta = data.data.__metadata;
  } else {
    extractedData = data;
  }
  return extractedData;
});

});

myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider','BackandProvider', function (nga, BackandProvider, $scope) {
// create an admin application

BackandProvider.setAppName('');
BackandProvider.setSignUpToken('');
BackandProvider.setAnonymousToken('');

var admin = nga.application('Pocket Release Admin Manager')
  .baseApiUrl('https://api.backand.com/1/objects/'); // main API endpoint#








// Users
var user = nga.entity('users');
user.listView().fields([
    nga.field('firstName').isDetailLink(true),
    nga.field('lastName'),
    nga.field('email')
]);
user.creationView().fields([
    nga.field('firstName'),
    nga.field('lastName'),
    nga.field('email', 'email')
]);
user.editionView().fields(user.creationView().fields());
// add the user entity to the admin application
admin.addEntity(user);


// Platforms
var platforms = nga.entity('platforms');
platforms.listView().fields([
    nga.field('id'),
    nga.field('platform_name'),
]);
platforms.creationView().fields([
    nga.field('id'),
    nga.field('platform_name'),
    nga.field('platform_id')
]);
platforms.editionView().fields(platforms.creationView().fields());
admin.addEntity(platforms);

var data = {};

// Games
var games = nga.entity('games');
games.listView().fields([
    nga.field('id'),
    nga.field('game_title').isDetailLink(true),
    nga.field('game_url'),
    nga.field('platforms', 'reference')
            .targetEntity(platforms)
            .targetField(nga.field('platform_name'))
            .label('Platform')
]);
games.creationView().fields([
    nga.field('game_title'),
    nga.field('image').template('<img ng-src="{{game_url}}" ng-show="game_url">'),
    nga.field('game_url', 'file').uploadInformation({'url':'', 'apifilename':'game_url'}).template('<div ng-controller="main"><label class="btn btn-default btn-file">Browse<input id="fileInput" field="::field" value="entry.values[{{main}}]" entry="entry" entity="::entity" form="formController.form" datastore="::formController.dataStore" type="file" style="display: none;" accept="*/*" ng-click="initUpload()" /></label></div>', true),
    nga.field('platforms'),
    nga.field('game_description'),
    nga.field('game_boxart'),
    nga.field('game_release_uk', 'date'),
    nga.field('game_release_us', 'date'),
    nga.field('game_release_eu', 'date')
]);
games.editionView().fields(games.creationView().fields());
admin.addEntity(games);



// Dash


admin.dashboard(nga.dashboard()
    .addCollection(nga.collection(games)
        .name('total_games')
        .title('Total Games')
        .fields([
            nga.field('game_title')
        ])
        .sortField('game_title')
        .sortDir('DESC')
        .order(1)
    ).template(`
        <div class="row dashboard-starter"></div>
        <dashboard-summary></dashboard-summary>
        <div class="row dashboard-content">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <ma-dashboard-panel collection="dashboardController.collections.total_games" entries="dashboardController.entries.total_games" datastore="dashboardController.datastore"></ma-dashboard-panel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `));


// Menu Customize

// customize menu
  admin.menu(nga.menu()
      .addChild(nga.menu(user).icon('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> ')) // customize the entity menu icon
      .addChild(nga.menu(games).icon('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> ')) // you can even use utf-8 symbols!
      .addChild(nga.menu(platforms).icon('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span> '))
  );



// attach the admin application to the DOM and execute it
nga.configure(admin);
}]);


myApp.controller('main', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, Backand) {

    // Image upload stuff

    $scope.initUpload = function(){

        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
          imageChanged(fileInput);
        });
      }


    function imageChanged(fileInput) {

        //read file content
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          upload(file.name, e.currentTarget.result).then(function(res) {
            $scope.imageUrl = res.data.url;
            $scope.filename = file.name;
            return res.data.url;
          }, function(err){
            alert(err.data);
          });
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      };



    function upload(filename, filedata) {
        // By calling the files action with POST method in will perform 
        // an upload of the file into Backand Storage
        return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url : Backand.getApiUrl()+'/1/objects/action/games',
          params:{  
            "name": 'files'
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          // you need to provide the file name and the file data
          data: {
            "filename": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + ''+ filename.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+$/i),
            "filedata": filedata.substr(filedata.indexOf(',') + 1, filedata.length) //need to remove the file prefix type
          }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                //$scope.game_url = data.url;
                //$("#game_url").addClass("ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched").removeClass("ng-pristine ng-untouched");
                //$("#game_boxart").val(data.url).addClass("ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched").removeClass("ng-pristine ng-untouched");
                return data.url;

         });
      };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a PUT call to backand in order to save this url in the relevant column?

```
return $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          url : Backand.getApiUrl()+'/1/objects/games/YOUR_GAME_ID',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data: {
            urlColumn:imageUrl
          }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        .....
         });
```